# USB detection app shows nothing in Android 4.0.3 Smile Pro when i connect any USB

Tags: java, android

I am using Eclipse and I have installed the app in my Android phone.

**Main Activity Code :**

package com.example.usbdetection;

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
 import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



UsbManager usbManager;
    PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
    UsbDevice usbDevice;
    Intent intent;
    final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.example.usbdetection.USB_PERMISSION";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
    }

private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {

                usbDevice = (UsbDevice) intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                usbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice, mPermissionIntent);

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                        UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if (usbDevice != null) {
                        // call method to set up device communication

                        int deviceId = usbDevice.getDeviceId();
                        int productId = usbDevice.getProductId();
                        Log.i("device id", "****" + deviceId);
                        Log.i("product id", "****" + productId);

                    } else {
                        Log.i("device id", "No USB device");
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d("shiv", "permission denied for device ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

}

Manifest file :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.usbdetection.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

When I run my app and connect any USB it shows nothing. whats wrong?.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

**First i rooted my android device.**
and then i added a file named **android.hardware.usb.host.xml** in **etc/permissions** Folder which include permission

```
 <permissions>
 <feature name="android.hardware.usb.host" /> 
 </permissions>
```

And now it supports Host API.